# Get access to a class thru a new instance

Tags: java

I'm using the code above to create a new object from a class :

```
Object obj = Class.forName("myClass").newInstance()
```

But for some reason I can't use the var obj to execute methods or get variables from the class 'myClass', like this :

```
obj.methodFromMyClass();
```

The point of this is to create dynamically a object from class 'myClass' thru parameters of another Class.

**Class *A***

```
public A () {

    B b = new B("myClass"); 

}
```

**Class *B***

```
public B ( String className ) {

    Object obj = Class.forName( className ).newInstance(); 
    obj.methodFromMyClass(); 

}
```

**Class *myClass***

```
public void methodFromMyClass () {

    // Some code

}
```

So Class B supposedly should work like a bridge creating the object from the indicated class at its parameters .

Every hint is welcome .

Comment: Give a look to the [Factory Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) `obj` to `myClass` so that the compiler knows what type of object it is:

```
((myClass) obj).methodFromMyClass();
```

If you are going to use methods from `myClass` repeatedly on `obj`, you might like to assign it to a new variable which explicitly declares the class:

```
myClass myObj = (myClass) myObj;
myObj.aMethodFromMyClass();
myObj.anotherMethodFromMyClass();
```

---

If you do not know the type of `obj` at compile time, you may need to use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to call `methodFromMyClass`, e.g.

```
obj.getClass().getMethod("methodFromMyClass", new Object[0]).invoke(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you about the explanation, but it's not exactly what I'm searching for, I'm creating it from dynamically, it could be myClass as well ClassAbc, classdbc , etc...

Comment: You are the best thing that happened to me today :D thank you, I was searching this for days, btw  this way will delay more than the simple one right ? Looks to be less efficient.

Comment: Will definitely take you longer to code this way :p  For execution it will be less efficient, but in most cases the difference is unlikely to be noticeable.

Comment: Do you know any book about this things, where I can study java from the most deep ? Where I can get from the easy stuff to hardcore.

Comment: @VladimirLisovets I'd guess Joshua Bloch's _Effective Java_ would be a good one

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `obj` to the type of your class :

```
myClass obj = (myClass) Class.forName( className ).newInstance(); 
obj.methodFromMyClass();
```

Since your class B constructor calls the method `methodFromMyClass`, it must know which type to cast `obj` to. That type must have the `methodFromMyClass` method. It doesn't have to be the exact type of the created instance. Any interface or super-class that the class of the created instance implements/extends will do, as long as they contain that method.

Comment: Casting 'obj' with the String 'className' isn't working but I'll research on this.

Comment: @VladimirLisovets No, you can't cast it using a String variable. It must be a hard coded type. If you don't know which type to cast it to at compile time, you can use reflection to find and call that method.